# How to fix Maven multimodule snapshot versions?

Tags: maven

In order to speed up the build process and reduce potential error sources, I want to fix all my snapshots dependencies which don't have a release to their latest versions. I first considered creating releases out of them (without changing the code as they are not my projects) but then wondered if it has the same effect of just including the version 1.0-XYZ instead of 1.0-SNAPSHOT.

Is that equivalent or does solely the position in a snapshot repository cause maven to check for new versions? And is it necessary to include all of the following or can I remove the snapshot?:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.somelib</groupId>
  <artifactId>somelib-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-20140130.123</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.somelib</groupId>
  <artifactId>somelib-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-20140130.456</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but if anyone is looking for this kind of answer, there is a maven plugin that helps you to do that :
http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/lock-snapshots.html

Best regards,